# How can I add an object to my hand in VR and make it move like my hand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, virtual-reality

I am developing a VR game and I want to press a button so that a GameObject spawns in my hand and replaces my hand so that it moves like it. I tried it like this:

```
 public Transform handSpawn;
 Instantiate(objectToSpawn, handSpawn.position, handSpawn.rotation);
```

For handSpawn I tried to take the controller itself, the model, and an anchor but neither of those did the job. I use the XR Toolkit

Comment: If you want it to move like your hand, just make it a child of your tracked object. So get the transform of the thing you have instantiated, and set its parent to be the tracked object's transform.

Comment: Can you show me an example maybe? I don't really understand what you mean :D